# How to draw lines on a plot of points in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How can one join the points with lines in the following code?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(1, 10):
    y = i**2
    plt.plot(i, y, '-o')
    plt.show
```

Using `plt.scatter` or `plt.scatter/plt.plot/plt.show` don't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code would not plot properly since **plt.plot** and **plt.show()** is looping. You might want to store your update **i** & **y** values in a list before you plot it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = []
y = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(i**2)

plt.plot(x,y) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. The documentation seemed to confine itself to array/list data. Is there any way to achieve this without forming these?